# easy_install pyzmq, cygwin. error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, gcc, cygwin, pyzmq

I am trying to run ipython notebook in cywgin. for this to work i need to install pyzmq. However this isnt working. i have attched the problem bellow, can anyone help?

```
$ easy_install pyzmq
Searching for pyzmq
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pyzmq/
Reading http://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq
Reading http://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/downloads
Reading http://github.com/zeromq/pyzmq/releases
Best match: pyzmq 14.0.1
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pyzmq/pyzmq-14.0.1.zip#md5=014e44ddcb1ede81a9087af5ec49470d
Processing pyzmq-14.0.1.zip
Writing /tmp/easy_install-CZx3rY/pyzmq-14.0.1/setup.cfg
Running pyzmq-14.0.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-CZx3rY/pyzmq-14.0.1/egg-dist-tmp-E_MUa0
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'docs/gh-pages'
warning: no directories found matching 'bundled/uuid'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/uuid/Makefile*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/Makefile*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bundled/zeromq/src/platform.hpp'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'zmq/libzmq*'
warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__/*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps/*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
warning: no previously-included files matching '.mailmap' found anywhere in distribution
Did not find libzmq via pkg-config:
Package libzmq was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libzmq.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libzmq' found

************************************************
Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
    Custom ZMQ dir:
build/temp.cygwin-1.7.27-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c:4:17: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zmq.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Failed with default libzmq, trying again with /usr/local
************************************************
Configure: Autodetecting ZMQ settings...
    Custom ZMQ dir:       /usr/local
build/temp.cygwin-1.7.27-x86_64-2.7/scratch/vers.c:4:17: fatal error: zmq.h: No such file or directory
 #include "zmq.h"
                 ^
compilation terminated.

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

************************************************
Warning: Failed to build or run libzmq detection test.

If you expected pyzmq to link against an installed libzmq, please check to make sure:

    * You have a C compiler installed
    * A development version of Python is installed (including headers)
    * A development version of ZMQ >= 2.1.4 is installed (including headers)
    * If ZMQ is not in a default location, supply the argument --zmq=<path>
    * If you did recently install ZMQ to a default location,
      try rebuilding the ld cache with `sudo ldconfig`
      or specify zmq's location with `--zmq=/usr/local`

You can skip all this detection/waiting nonsense if you know
you want pyzmq to bundle libzmq as an extension by passing:

    `--zmq=bundled`

I will now try to build libzmq as a Python extension
unless you interrupt me (^C) in the next 10 seconds...

 1...
************************************************
Using bundled libzmq
already have bundled/zeromq
attempting ./configure to generate platform.hpp
Warning: failed to configure libzmq:
/bin/sh: ./configure: No such file or directory

staging platform.hpp from: /tmp/easy_install-CZx3rY/pyzmq-14.0.1/buildutils/include_linux
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lsodium
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Warning: libsodium not found, zmq.CURVE security will be unavailable
************************************************
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from bundled/zeromq/src/poller.hpp:42:0,
                 from bundled/zeromq/src/socket_base.hpp:30,
                 from bundled/zeromq/src/ctx.cpp:31:
bundled/zeromq/src/epoll.hpp:28:23: fatal error: sys/epoll.h: No such file or directory
 #include <sys/epoll.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Did you install `gcc` c compiler?

Comment: Which OS r u using ??

Comment: the OS is wondows but if i use the windows binary, it wants to install it in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 1):

Install a pre-compiled windows binary if you are using windows.

For example from Gohlke's great directory of windows binaries: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyzmq

Answer (score 1):

I just went through the same process. As the PyZMQ Readme.md says:

> When compiling pyzmq (e.g. installing with pip on Linux),
>   it is generally recommended that zeromq be installed separately, via homebrew, apt, yum, etc.
>   If this is not available, pyzmq will *try* to build libzmq as a Python Extension,
>   though this is not guaranteed to work.

So as in my case, in your case it didn't work. You can either use Cygwin to install zeromq or download it yourself: http://zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software (I went for the latest, Stable Release 4.0.4)

unztar, configure (`--prefix=/my/home/local` if you wish), make install

Then you need to `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/my/home/local/lib/pkgconfig` (or whatever your default lib directory is, e.g. `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`).

Make sure this path exists:

```
/my/home/local/lib/pkgconfig/libzmq.pc
```

Finally `pip install pyzmq` and it should pick up the `libzmq.pc` file you've just built.